# Determine whether $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n - 1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine whether the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ converges or not.

I first broke the sequence up into partial fractions to obtain

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty -\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1}$$
$$=  \sum_{n=2}^\infty -\frac{1}{n} + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n-1} $$

The first series is a harmonic series and so it diverges. The second series is bigger than an ordinary harmonic series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ and so by direct comparison if the harmonic series diverges so must $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n-1}$. Both series diverge and it is known that the sum of two divergent series could be either divergent or convergent. I am not sure how to determine if this series converges - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By method of difference, it likely will converge. I'll double check again.

Comment: It does converge and the sum is 1. I'm just not sure how to get to this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=&\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\\
&=\lim_{N \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}\\
&+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\\
&+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\\
&\vdots\\
&+\frac{1}{N-1}-\frac{1}{N} \bigg)\\
&=\lim_{N \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\\
&=1
\end{align}
Clearly the series converges.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=2}^k\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{k\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\cdots-\frac{1}{k}\right)=\lim_{k\to \infty}1-\frac{1}{k}=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=1-\frac{1}{m}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the limit comparison test
$$
\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\bigg/n^{-2}\to1
$$
as $n\to\infty$. Since $\sum n^{-2}$ converges, your series converges as well.